# Background doesn't show in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header with logo and navigation. the logo is background. it shows correctly in all browsers except internet explorer. here is the HTML for header:

```
    <div id="header"><div id="navigation"><ul>
<li>
<a href="#" >Home</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#">Profile</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#">Topics</a>
</li><li>
<a href="#">Chat</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and here's the css:

```
    #header{
position:fixed;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
z-index:1000;
width:100%;
height:48px;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation{
    padding-left:50px;
background:url("http://localhost/img/logo/purple.png")no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    min-height:48px;
     z-index:1010;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

can someone please tell me why the background image doesn't show in IE? it shows in all the other browsers !

Comment: In what version of IE did you try your code?

Comment: Works here (IE11) http://jsfiddle.net/kLk4A/

Comment: @Tamara I am using IE 8

Comment: Maybe you need a space between  `url("")` and `no-repeat`

Comment: Oh, also, min-height may be the issue.. IDK if IE8 likes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
background-image:url('http://localhost/img/logo/purple.png');
```

Comment: Nope, that's not necessary.  `background:` works just as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to have space between `background:url("http://localhost/img/logo/purple.png")` and `no-repeat;`:

```
background:url("http://localhost/img/logo/purple.png") no-repeat;
```

Also - don't use that URL for the image - it will work only when page is browsed from your own computer. Use relative `/img/logo/purple.png` URL instead.